# Spark distinct performance issue after joining

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I  reading a parquet file

```
val df1 = sqlContext.read.parquet("")
df1.count = 5000000 records
val df2 = df1.select("id","aid", "DId" , "dd" , "mm", "yy","TO")
  .distinct()
  .groupBy("id","aid", "DId" , "dd" , "mm","yy","TO")
  .count()
  .filter($"count" > 1)
  .select("id","aid", "DId" , "dd" , "mm", "yy")
val df3 = df2.join(df1,
  df2("cid") <=> df1("cid") && 
  df2("aid") <=> df1("aid") && 
  df2("did") <=> df1("did") && 
  df2("dd") <=> df1("dd") && 
  df2("mm") <=> df1("mm") && 
  df2("yy") <=> df1("yy"), "inner")
  .distinct()
```

when I do df3.count ... It is taking nearly 897517ms which is too high it is impacting overall job execution and some times job is aborted If I Increase the timeout option it is execution  but latency is too high . I need suggestion to improve this

Comment: Regarding your code for definition of `df2`, I assume that df2 will always be empty. You do a distinct() which will return one row per "keys". Then the filter($"count" > 1) will eliminate every row. Is that what you wanted to do ?

Comment: My intention is similar to sql Query `SELECT cid,aid, DId, dd, mm, yy FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        cid,aid, DId, dd, mm, yy, TO
    FROM
        nsc
    WHERE
        cid = 1) t
GROUP BY cid,aid, DId, dd, mm, yy
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;` I converted it to dataframe

Comment: distinct is a very expensive operation, try to avoid it if possible. If you don't need exact numbers, try to replace .distinct().count() with .approx_count_distinct(...). If you do need exact numbers - use .countDistinct(...) - I believe it works faster. Note, that in both cases you need to import functions._ before

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment :

> My intention is similar to sql Query SELECT cid,aid, DId, dd, mm, yy FROM (SELECT DISTINCT cid,aid, DId, dd, mm, yy, TO FROM nsc WHERE cid = 1) t GROUP BY cid,aid, DId, dd, mm, yy HAVING COUNT(*) > 1; I converted it to dataframe

I think the correct code should be :

```
      df
        .select("id", "aid", "DId", "dd", "mm", "yy", "TO")
        .distinct()
        .filter(col("cid") <=> 1)
        .groupBy("id", "aid", "DId", "dd", "mm", "yy")
        .count()
        .filter(col("count") > 1)
        .select("id", "aid", "DId", "dd", "mm", "yy")
```

So no need to do a final join. It should be faster.

Comment: I wonder I have the same query posted in the question how it will eliminate the need of second query

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Did you manage to make it work ?